# Wordpress Category Query Selector not working and how to target Custom Fields

Tags: wordpress, sorting, categories

I'm adjusting a category template for a friend with the following code:
http://jsfiddle.net/misfitint/8h4h1x1w/

Snippet: `<?php query_posts($order.'&order=ASC&cat=9');  ?>`

Full code in jsfiddle link above.

It does not appear to adjust the listing when clicked on, however. I've changed it from ASC to DESC but the listing still remains the same.  Am I missing something?

I also want to be able to sort by custom fields and am not sure how to build the array to make that happen.  Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

query_posts() is for the main loop only. Try [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => $_GET['sort'],
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    'cat'     => 9
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: I was reading through this article this morning: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/14/using-wp_query-wordpress

And while it works fine for listing the categories, being able to allow the reader sort them is still an issue with the original code above.  Can $sort= $_GET['sort']; work with wp_query?